# bazel, rules_docker - java_image with arm64?

Tags: bazel, apple-m1

I am trying to run ((minikube with docker driver), rules_k8s, rules_docker) on apple silicon (m1). I could run this bazel build with apple intel.

But when I run same build on m1, my java pod die with SIGILL.
From pod's log, it seems to run with java for `amd64`(not `arm64`).

How can I build `java_image` for arm64?

Now I am using below bazel code.

```
load("@io_bazel_rules_docker//java:image.bzl", "java_image")

java_image(
    name = "image",
    runtime_deps = [...],
    jvm_flags = [...],
    main_class = "...",
)
```

---

Pod's log

```
#
# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#
#  SIGILL (0x4) at pc=0x000000401470c125, pid=1, tid=9
#
# JRE version: OpenJDK Runtime Environment (11.0.13+8) (build 11.0.13+8-post-Debian-1deb11u1)
# Java VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (11.0.13+8-post-Debian-1deb11u1, mixed mode, tiered, compressed oops, g1 gc, linux-amd64)
# Problematic frame:
# J 4416 c1 java.lang.String.hashCode()I java.base@11.0.13 (49 bytes) @ 0x000000401470c125 [0x000000401470c100+0x0000000000000025]
#
# Core dump will be written. Default location: //core
#
# An error report file with more information is saved as:
# //hs_err_pid1.log
Compiled method (c2)   34765 2778       4       java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap::get (162 bytes)
 total in heap  [0x000000401b4fde10,0x000000401b4fe4e8] = 1752
 relocation     [0x000000401b4fdf88,0x000000401b4fdfb0] = 40
 main code      [0x000000401b4fdfc0,0x000000401b4fe280] = 704
 stub code      [0x000000401b4fe280,0x000000401b4fe298] = 24
 metadata       [0x000000401b4fe298,0x000000401b4fe2a0] = 8
 scopes data    [0x000000401b4fe2a0,0x000000401b4fe3c8] = 296
 scopes pcs     [0x000000401b4fe3c8,0x000000401b4fe488] = 192
 dependencies   [0x000000401b4fe488,0x000000401b4fe490] = 8
 handler table  [0x000000401b4fe490,0x000000401b4fe4d8] = 72
 nul chk table  [0x000000401b4fe4d8,0x000000401b4fe4e8] = 16
Could not load hsdis-amd64.so; library not loadable; PrintAssembly is disabled
#
# If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:
#   https://bugs.debian.org/openjdk-11
#
```

Answer (score 0):

`java_image`(from rules_docker) uses base attr for image.
And default base attr in rules_docker is [DEFAULT_JAVA_BASE](https://github.com/bazelbuild/rules_docker/blob/master/java/image.bzl#L94-L99). It is actually `@java_image_base//image`.

`@java_image_base//image` is declared in [repositories()](https://github.com/bazelbuild/rules_docker/blob/master/java/image.bzl#L57-L63).
And it uses gcr.io/distroless/java:latest ([link](https://github.com/bazelbuild/rules_docker/blob/master/java/java.bzl#L25)).

And I had to use another image for arm64.

---

I could use `distroless/java11-debian11:debug-arm64` by rule `container_pull` and specifing `base` attr in `java_image`.

BUILD

```
java_image(
    name = "image",
    base = "@java11_arm64//image",
    ...
)
```

WORKSPACE

```
container_pull(
  name = "java11_arm64",
  registry = "gcr.io",
  repository = "distroless/java11-debian11",
  digest = "sha256:2184282f01097038fcf83b86196e225ae079b973c8fe9960f8db4961c5662388",
)
```